# red5chat installation

Tags: flash, apache-flex, red5

Can any one give installation steps for [red5chat application](http://www.red5chat.com/)?

I am facing problem with java red5 part and don't know how to compile it, or where exactly to put it.

Comment: I still have problem with it , did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Check here http://www.freedevelopment.net/articles/free-red5chat.html

Answer (score 0):

You will also need Adobe flash CS3 to edit the files so it can point to your Red5 server.

This free software has poor documentation, but just ask and i will help you as much as i can.. i've got everything working exept connecting my own users from Mysql.